# How to add custom mailheader using cdo.message in Vb6

Tags: vb6, cdo.message

I have tried to use the following code to add custom mail header in VB6. But it didnt work.
Can anyone help me out?

```
Dim lobj_cdomsg As CDO.Message
Set lobj_cdomsg = New CDO.Message

'Add the Project Reference Miscrosoft CDO WINDOWS FOR 2000
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPServer) = "servername"
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 30
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSendUsingMethod) = 2
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = 1
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSendUserName) = "username"
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSendPassword) = "password"
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPServerPort) = "587"
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-MC-Tags") = "CKSR001"
'lobj_cdomsg.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-MC-Tags") = "CKSR002"
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Update

lobj_cdomsg.To = "to user"
lobj_cdomsg.From = "from"
lobj_cdomsg.Subject = "FROM VB6 CODSYS"
lobj_cdomsg.TextBody = "New Mail"
lobj_cdomsg.TextBody = "New Mail"
lobj_cdomsg.Send
Set lobj_cdomsg = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add your "urn:schemas:mailheader:X-..." header as a field of the Message object, not Message.Configuration.

Add the following two lines before sending the message: (and remove your non-working line)

```
lobj_cdomsg.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-MC-Tags") = "CKSR001"
lobj_cdomsg.Fields.Update
```

Then it should work.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue, and did not realize I had to issue the update call against the fields.  thanks!